# Lemon tree drops its leaves

Tags: trees, houseplants, leaves, diseases, tree-care

We bought this lemon tree about a month ago. It was in a good condition when we purchased it.

At first, we placed it outside, and for the last ten days, we brought it inside, situated right in front of the window. When we placed it outside, the weather fluctuated between 12 and 19C. Now inside, the temperature is about 20C.

When we brought it home, it started to gradually drop its leaves. I am attaching the pictures of the leaves.

I would be eternally grateful for helping to identiy what the problem with this tree is. We really wish to preserve this tree.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]